# Communication between two different networks using java socket programming

Tags: java

I wrote a Server-side Socket program[java program] in my laptop and a client-side socket program in my friends laptop. Both are connected to the same wifi and it works fine but when I connect server-socket laptop to my mobile data network it doesn't.

I have tried using IP address which comes when we connect to the network but it gives me an error on client side.

Server-side code

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Server Demo
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
try 
{
int n=0;
ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(9999);
while(n!=1)
{
System.out.println("Waiting for Client!");
Socket sc=ss.accept();
BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(sc.getInputStream()));
PrintStream out=new PrintStream(sc.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s1=in.readLine();
System.out.println("From Client="+s1);
System.out.println("Enter the Message:");
String s2=br.readLine();
out.println(s2);
n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}
}
catch(Exception e1)
{
System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Client side code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class CDemo
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
 {
try
{
Socket cc=new Socket("192.168.0.103",9999);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
PrintStream out=new PrintStream(cc.getOutputStream(),true);
BufferedReaderin=newBufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(cc.getInputStream());
System.out.println("Enter the Message:");
String s=br.readLine();
out.println(s);
String s1=in.readLine();
System.out.println(s1);
out.println(1);
cc.close();
}
catch(Exception e1)
{
System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error even? Did you do port forwarding so the router knows where to move the traffic to?

Comment: Please fix your formatting, Also, do not absorb important exception info... at least do `e.printStackTrace()`, it contains so much more good info than only the error message itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got it your question: you're trying to connect with server-side in one network, and the client-side on another network. But this does not to work, because each side cannot see the other, this happens because the programs aren't in the same range of IP addresses; they need to stay in the same network to the router give IP addresses that are visible to each other.

Comment: that what my question is if i want to access different network range ip addresses then  what should i do...plz help

Comment: but if you want make the computers reachable from the outside, you will need use internet connection, like deploying your program to a heroku machine, or just configure a gateway, a gateway is a node in a computer network that passes traffic from a local network to other networks or the Internet.

Comment: I don't know much about networks or configuring them, and i cannot help with it.